# How to properly compare these two confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, nltk

I have used Vader, a sentiment analysis tool for social media, on a database of movie reviews. These two confusion matrices differ in the vader.py algorithm, as the first one is from nltk:

[image]

The second one is deriving from Vader's original code on github and includes fixes to negation words, etc.

[image]

I was wondering how could I properly compare the two, as I'm not really able to read them. It seems there is not a big difference between them and I don't understand what could be the sources of the errors here.

Comment: What do you want to compare?

Comment: the two results given by the matrix, that is to say, two versions of the vader.py algorithm for sentiment classification (1 being very negative and 5 very positive).

Comment: In what way do you want to compare them? You already know that they are slightly different.

Comment: I just can't read the results

Comment: What do you mean that you can't read the results?

Comment: I can't understand what it means basically: what is the difference between them

Comment: Do you not know what a confusion matrix tells you? Do the decimal numbers instead of integers throw you off?

Comment: yes, also I make confusion between the anti-diagonal and what's outside. I know I have to read what's outside but I can't understand what are the most "relevant" cells I have to look at!

Comment: You should not compare the confusion matrices directly but the metrics that derive from it, like f1, roc_auc, precision, recall, etc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about interpreting these confusion matrices: the sum of every row is 1, which implies that every value is a conditional probability `p( predicted label | true label )`, i.e. the probability of a given true label to be a particular predicted label. Example: the top left cell in both matrices is 0.01, which means that when the true label is 5 the probability that the system predicts label 1 is 1%.

The two confusion matrices show the results of the predictions *by two different systems*. This means that in general there is not one which is correct and the other which makes errors, just two different ways to predict labels which might lead to different types of errors.

- The diagonal shows the True Positive cases, i.e. cases where the predicted label is the same as the true label (this is important since these are the "correct" cases). The probabilities show very little difference between the two systems on the diagonal, the top one being slightly better for labels 3 and 4 and the bottom one slightly better for label 5.
- In general it's important not to look only at the diagonal especially for ordinal values, because if the predicted value is far from the true value it's a more serious error than if it's close to it. Example: if the true value is 4 it's better for a system to predict 3 than 1 (both are errors but the latter is worse). However here again there is very little difference between the two systems, they appear to have a very similar behaviour.

In order to quantitatively summarize and compare the performance of the two systems, confusion matrices are too complex. Typically one would use an appropriate evaluation measure, for instance micro or macro f-score (classification evaluation) or Mean Absolute Error (regression evaluation).